# Specify file name for download with wget without overwriting

Tags: linux, bash, unix, wget

I know already that you can specify the file name of a download done with wget via the -O parameter. But in case the file already exists it gets overwritten. If you don't specify a file name wget never overwrites a file, it just appends a .1, .2, .3 and so on. I want to have that append solution for my specified file name. Is that possible?

Comment: this isn't a programming question, unix.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that will append numbers if needed to find a file name which doesn't yet exist:

```
newfile () {
    fname=$1
    count=0
    while [ -e "$fname" ]
    do
        fname="$1.$((++count))"
    done
    echo "$fname"
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$ ls
$ newfile abc
abc
$ touch abc
$ newfile abc
abc.1
```

With `wget`, you might use it as:

```
wget http://example.com/index.html -O "$(newfile something)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the `-nc` or `--no-clobber` parameter? It skips the downloads that overwrites files ?

Comment: he doesn't want to skip them, he wants to append a version suffix.